# Conda environment with pip -e : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have a conda file with some standard dependencies and then I want to install a customer package using pip -e. My `environment.yml` looks like this:

```
name: my_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults

dependencies:
  - python==3.7.0 
  - pip==19.3.1
  - pip:
    - -e ./path_to_my_package
```

When I try to create the environment by running `conda env create -f conda.yml` the creation of the environment fails with an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'` . This is surprising, I have setuptools installed in the conda package and my Ubuntu.

The command conda tries to run and that throws an error is:

```
/home/path/to/my/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/path/to/my/package/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/pat/to/my/package/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
```

When I run this command outside of the `conda create` command, it works well.

My `setup.py` looks simple, it is just:

```
import setuptools

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setuptools.setup()
```

I am stunned. Can anybody help?

*EDIT*

I am on Windows Subsystem for Linux (version 1)

Comment: `setuptools` is an explicit dependency for `pip`, so yeah, very odd. Could you try it with single `=` instead of  `==` in the dependencies section? Technically, the double equals is not in the Conda spec (that's Pip syntax), but not sure that that would be the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does your package has the approriate section in, e.g., `pyproject.toml` file like this

```
[metadata]
name = "mypackage"
version = "0.0.1"

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

See also [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) (Note the quotation marks in `[metadata]`)

Comment: This was the solution! I had `pyproject.toml` files in my packages and did not update the `[build-system]` section. After adding setuptools there - as proposed by you - the pip install worked fine.